# 'go' was not declare in this scope (C++)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, scope, stack

I've tried declaring but still wrong and I've tried several other ways but still error, Can you help me?Sorry I new to Programming
['go' not declare in this scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsEg8.png)what do i have to do?

this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void push (void);
void pop (void);
void gotoxy(int x, int y);

int x, top;
int s [5], N=5;

main()
{
    char pilih;
    char barloop;
      system ("cls");
      gotoxy ( 25,7 ); puts ("coba stack");  ;
      gotoxy ( 25,10 ); puts ("1.  push");
      gotoxy ( 25,13 ); puts ("2.  pop");   
      gotoxy ( 25,16 ); puts ("3.  exit");
      gotoxy ( 25,19 );  printf("Pilih :");
      scanf (" %x  " , &pilih);
      switch(pilih)
      {
        case 1: printf ("\n masukkan data x=;"),
                scanf (" ");    push(); getch();  break;
        case 2: pop (); getch(); break;
        case 3: exit(0);
      }
     go to char barloop;
    }

void pop (void)
{
    if  (top > 0)
    {
        
    }
    else { printf("\n\r stack kosong"); }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: 1. [Edit] your post and add the code as text, as we cannot copy-paste an image. 2. That's not how you use a `goto`, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. ok thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, there is no `go to` keyword in C++. It's `goto` with no space.
- Second, your `goto` sentence isn't right in syntax. `goto` syntax looks like this:

```cpp
dothisagian: // this is a statement label
// code
goto dothisagian;
```

It doesn't magically jump into what line you wrote. It jumps to the statement label.

- Third, you have to write what return value `main()` is.

So, your code should look like this:

```cpp
int main() // main returns an int
{
doThisAgain:
    char barloop;
    // code
    goto doThisAgain;
}
```

- One last note: You shouldn't really use `goto` in C++ unless necessary. You should use one of the three types of loops instead.

Answer (score -1):

The keyword is `goto` with no space.

Comment: I tried and still error.

Comment: Yea, I don't see any labels. If you want to jump to the `char barloop;` line then you need to add a label. Then goto that label.

Comment: Ok I'll try, thanks for the help